# No facets showing in Sitecore Search when using SOLR

Tags: content-search, solr, buckets, content-tree

There is no facets showing when I change the search provider to SOLR.

[image]

The sample item here is the Content item.

Comment: did you rebuild indexes after your change search provider?

Comment: Yes I rebuild all the indexes and also try to check the index by using the SOLR page, there are results from my query. The search content works fine when I use Lucene, there are results and facets. If I use the default query(which I use in Lucene) in SOLR,  there are 0 results and No facets.

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate a solr scheme for the index?

Comment: Can you check in show config if "XConnect.Client.EnableDataExtraction" settings set to "true". I am not sure if it helps but it is for "This setting enables XConnect Collection and Search Client to access data extraction services."

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the log file to see if there are any error(s) related to SOLR? you can perform the following steps:
1) Review the log file and check for any error/exception related to SOLR connective or any specific config.
2) Rebuild the indexes. 
3) Now, review the log file again,and see if there are any errors logged.

Please reform above steps and let me know how it goes?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Tagging/Tagging/__Semantics" field is a Multilist With Search field?

Also, if you created additional tag items under "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Facets", try to remove them and test again.